# Find occurrences of huge list of phrases in text

Tags: python

I'm building a backend and trying to crunch the following problem.

- The clients submit text to the backend (around `2000` characters on average)
- Backend endpoint that receives the request has to apply phrase highlighting to the submitted text
- There is around `80k` phrases to match. A phrase is a simple object:

  ```
  {
      'phrase': 'phrase to match'
      'link': 'link_url'
  }
  ```
- After finding all matches of phrases that exist in the text, the backend returns to the client what was matched - basically a map:

  ```
  range in text -> phrase
  ```

Most is done. I'm about to tackle coding the phrase matching part. Everything else works smoothly. Since I don't want to reinvent the wheel I tried googling to find a Python library that does the job of efficiently finding phrases (from huge list) in text. However, I couldn't find anything.

I checked out the [BlueSoup](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/) and [Natural Language Toolkit](https://www.nltk.org/). However they don't seem to be doing what I'm looking for.

Do you guys know if there is a library that would be helpful in such task? Seems like a common thing to implement and I don't want to go custom if there is a well established library for that.

Comment: For people voting to close it: I checked the guidelines, whether to post it here or in `Software Engineering` or other stack exchange and it is clear to me `StackOverflow` is the right site. If you vote to close, please comment and let me know where to move it.

Comment: One of the suggested algorithms would fit. You could also use Python's `str.find` (loop through slices of the text if you need all occurences). Python's regular expression module would also do the job.
You could even easily spawn a Pool of workers with Python's multiprocessing module and map over the requests to speed up the process.

Comment: Are you sure, that apply precompiled huge regexp is not fast enough?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

To get a reasonable speed while matching 80k patterns, you definitely need some preprocessing on the patterns, single-shot algorithms like `Boyer-Moore` won't help much.

You'll probably also need to do the work in compiled code (think C extension) to get reasonable throughput. Regarding how to preprocess the patterns - one option is state machines like `Aho-Corasick` or some generic [finite state transducer](http://www.openfst.org). The next option is something like a `suffix array` based index, and the last one that comes to my mind is inverted index.

If your matches are exact and the patterns respect word boundaries, chances are that a well implemented word or word-ngram keyed `inverted index` will be fast enough even in pure Python. The index is not a complete solution, it will rather give you a few candidate phrases which you need to check with normal string matching for a complete match.

If you need approximate matching, character-ngram inverted index is your choice.

Regarding real implementations - [flashtext](https://github.com/vi3k6i5/flashtext) mentioned in other answer here seems to be a reasonable pure Python solution if you're OK with the full-phrase-only limitation.

Otherwise you can get reasonable results with generic multi-pattern capable regexp libraries: one of the fastest should be Intel's [hyperscan](https://www.hyperscan.io/) - there are even some rudimentary [python](https://github.com/darvid/python-hyperscan) [bindings](https://github.com/grrrrrrrrr/hyperscan-python) available.

Other option is Google's [RE2](https://github.com/google/re2/) with [Python bindings](https://github.com/facebook/pyre2) from Facebook. You want to use `RE2::Set` in this case.

Answer (score 6):

Maybe you should try [flashtext](https://github.com/vi3k6i5/flashtext).
According to the author, it is much more faster than Regex.
[image]

The author even published a [paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/1711.00046) for this library.

I've personally tried this library for one of my project, in my opinion its API is quite friendly and usable.

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 5):

I faced an almost identical problem with my own chat page system. I wanted to be able to add a link to a number of keywords (with slight variations) that were present in the text. I only had around 200 `phrases` though to check.

I decided to try using a standard regular expression for the problem to see how fast it would be. The main bottleneck was in constructing the regular expression. I decided to pre-compile this and found the match time was very fast for shorter texts.

The following approach takes a list of `phrases`, where each contains `phrase` and `link` keys. It first constructs a reverse lookup dictionary:

```
{'phrase to match' : 'link_url', 'another phrase' : 'link_url2'}
```

Next it compiles a regular expression in the following form, this allows for matches which contain different amounts of white space between words:

```
(phrase\s+to\s+match|another\s+phrase)
```

Then for each piece of text (e.g. 2000 words each), it uses `finditer()` to get each match. The `match` object gives you `.span()` giving the start and end location of the matching text and `group(1)` gives the matched text. As the text can possibly have extra whitespace, `re_whitespace` is first applied to remove it and bring it back to the form stored in the `reverse` dictionary. With this, it is possible to automatically look up the required `link`:

```
import re

texts = ['this is a phrase   to    match', 'another phrase this  is']
phrases = [{'phrase': 'phrase to match', 'link': 'link_url'}, {'phrase': 'this is', 'link': 'link_url2'}]

reverse = {d['phrase']:d['link'] for d in sorted(phrases, key=lambda x: x['phrase'])}
re_whitespace = re.compile(r'\s+')
re_phrases = re.compile('({})'.format('|'.join(d['phrase'].replace(' ', r'\s+') for d in phrases)))

for text in texts:
    matches = [(match.span(), reverse[re_whitespace.sub(' ', match.group(1))]) for match in re_phrases.finditer(text)]
    print(matches)
```

Which would display the matches for the two texts as:

```
[((0, 7), 'link_url2'), ((10, 30), 'link_url')]
[((15, 23), 'link_url2')]
```

---

To test how this scales, I have tested it by importing a list of English words from `nltk` and automatically creating `80,000` two to six word phrases along with unique links. I then timed it on two suitably long texts:

```
import re
import random
from nltk.corpus import words
import time

english = words.words()

def random_phrase(l=2, h=6):
    return ' '.join(random.sample(english, random.randint(l, h)))


texts = ['this is a phrase   to    match', 'another phrase this  is']
# Make texts ~2000 characters
texts = ['{} {}'.format(t, random_phrase(200, 200)) for t in texts]

phrases = [{'phrase': 'phrase to match', 'link': 'link_url'}, {'phrase': 'this is', 'link': 'link_url2'}]
#Simulate 80k phrases
for x in range(80000):
    phrases.append({'phrase': random_phrase(), 'link': 'link{}'.format(x)})

construct_time = time.time()    

reverse = {d['phrase']:d['link'] for d in phrases}
re_whitespace = re.compile(r'\s+')
re_phrases = re.compile('({})'.format('|'.join(d['phrase'].replace(' ', r'\s+') for d in sorted(phrases, key=lambda x: len(x['phrase'])))))

print('Time to construct:', time.time() - construct_time)
print()

for text in texts:
    start_time = time.time()
    print('{} characters - "{}..."'.format(len(text), text[:60]))
    matches = [(match.span(), reverse[re_whitespace.sub(' ', match.group(1))]) for match in re_phrases.finditer(text)]
    print(matches)
    print('Time taken:', time.time() - start_time)        
    print()
```

This takes ~17 seconds to construct the regular expression and reverse lookup (which is only needed once). It then takes about 6 seconds per text. For very short text it takes ~0.06 seconds per text.

```
Time to construct: 16.812477111816406

2092 characters - "this is a phrase   to    match totaquine externize intoxatio..."
[((0, 7), 'link_url2'), ((10, 30), 'link_url')]
Time taken: 6.000027656555176

2189 characters - "another phrase this  is political procoracoidal playstead as..."
[((15, 23), 'link_url2')]
Time taken: 6.190425715255737
```

This will at least give you an idea to compare against.

Answer (score 3):

You should try a string search / pattern matching algorithm.
Most famous algorithm for you task is the [Aho-Corasick](http://blog.ivank.net/aho-corasick-algorithm-in-as3.html)
there is a python library for it [(of the top of google search)](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pyahocorasick)

Most of the pattern matching / string search algorithms will require you to convert your "bag of words/phrases" into a trie.

Comment: This helps when you are trying to find exact matches between phrases! This should definitely be upvoted more!

Answer (score 2):

The [pyparsing module](http://infohost.nmt.edu/tcc/help/pubs/pyparsing/web/index.html) - a python tool for extracting information from text - will help you with writing phrase matching. It returns all matches, and the index range of each match, of a phrase which you can describe using BNF (Backus-Naur Form) (i.e. a grammar). In my experience, it is easy to use ([2](http://pyparsing.wikispaces.com/)), expressive in terms of the kinds patterns you can define, and is impressively fast.

```
from pyparsing import Word, alphas
greet = Word( alphas ) + "," + Word( alphas ) + "!" # <-- grammar defined here
hello = "Hello, World!"
print (hello, "->", greet.parseString( hello ))
```

Use scanString to return index of match:

```
for item in greet.scanString(hello):
    print(item)

>>> ((['Hello', ',', 'World', '!'], {}), 0, 13)
```

If you assemble a list of phrases using pyparsing as a dictionary of form

```
phrase_list = {phrase_defined_with_pyparsing: phrase_name}
```

then your grammar can be a giant OR statement with labeled phrases.

```
import pyparsing as pp
your_grammar = pp.Or([phrase.setResultsName(phrase_name) for phrase, phrase_name in phrase_list.items()])
all_matches = your_grammar.scanString(big_document)
```

Each match is a tuple that is labeled (via setResultsName) and has an index range.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that the list of phrases changes over time and gets bigger, I'd recommend using a software, that already does, what you need. E.g. [elasticsearch](https://www.elastic.co/de/products/elasticsearch), it's open source and has a [Python client](https://elasticsearch-py.readthedocs.io/en/master/). If running a service like that in the background, this solves all you want and probably more than you ever can imagine. Also it's really not that hard to implement.

Answer (score 1):

You have much more pattern data than text data. Invert the problem: *match the patterns against the text*.

For the purposes of the this, I would assume that the text can be reasonably tokenized into words (or something word-like).  I'd also assume that the phrases, even if they can't be tokenized per se (for example because they are regexes) nevertheless usually contain words, and (most of the time) have to match at least one of the words they contain.

Here is a sketch of a solution which contains three parts:

1. Tokenize and index the patterns (once) - this produces a map of patterns that contain each token
2. Tokenize text and filter patterns to find candidates that *could* match the text
3. Test the candidate patterns and perform substitutions

Here is the code:

```
import re
import random
# from nltk.corpus import words
import time

""" Prepare text and phrases, same as in Martin Evans's answer """

# english = words.words()
with open('/usr/share/dict/american-english') as fh:
    english = [ x.strip() for x in fh.readlines() ]


def random_phrase(l=2, h=6):
    return ' '.join(random.sample(english, random.randint(l, h)))


texts = ['this is a phrase to match', 'another phrase this is']
# Make texts ~2000 characters
texts = ['{} {}'.format(t, random_phrase(200, 200)) for t in texts]

phrases = [{'phrase': 'phrase to match', 'link': 'link_url'}, {'phrase': 'this is', 'link': 'link_url2'}]
#Simulate 80k phrases
for x in range(80000):
    phrases.append({'phrase': random_phrase(), 'link': 'link{}'.format(x)})

""" Index the patterns """

construct_time = time.time()    

reverse = {d['phrase']:d['link'] for d in phrases}
re_phrases = [ re.compile(d['phrase'].replace(' ', r'\s+')) for d in phrases ]
re_whitespace = re.compile(r'\s+')

def tokenize(str):
    return str.split()

index = {}

for n in range(len(phrases)):
    tokens = tokenize(phrases[n]['phrase'])
    for token in tokens:
        if not token in index:
            index[token] = []
        index[token].append(n)

print('Time to construct:', time.time() - construct_time)
print()

for text in texts:
    start_time = time.time()
    print('{} characters - "{}..."'.format(len(text), text[:60]))

    """ Filter patterns to find candidates that *could* match the text """
    tokens = tokenize(text)
    phrase_ns = []

    for token in tokens:
        if not token in index:
           continue
        for n in index[token]:
            phrase_ns.append(n)

    phrase_ns = list(set(phrase_ns))

    """ Test the candidate patterns and perform substitutions """
    for n in phrase_ns:
        match = re.search(re_phrases[n], text)
        if match:
            print(match.span(), reverse[match.group()])
    print('Time taken:', time.time() - start_time)        
    print()
```

In my environment, this version creates an index in 16.2 seconds, and does the matching in 0.0042 and 0.0037 seconds (vs 4.7 seconds for the simple regex version, a ~1000x speedup).  The exact performance depends on the statistical properties of the text and phrases, of course, but this will almost always be a huge win.

Bonus: if a phrase must match several words (tokens), you can only add it to the index entry for the one *least common* token it must match, for another huge speedup.

Answer (score 0):

The "Patricia tree" is a good solution for this kind of problem. It's sort of a radix tree with the radix being the character choices involved. So to find if "the dog" is in the tree, you start at the root, tag the "t" branch, then the "h" branch, and so on. Except Patricia trees do this really fast.

So you spin your text through, and you can get all tree locations (=phrases) that hits. This will even get you overlapping matches if you want.

The main article about them is Donald R. Morrison, PATRICIA - Practical Algorithm to Retrieve Information Coded in Alphanumeric, Journal of the ACM, 15(4):514-534, October 1968. There's some discussion at https://xlinux.nist.gov/dads/HTML/patriciatree.html There are several implementations on github, though I don't know which are good.