# Find fuzzy search occurrences of a huge list of phrases in a large list of sentences

Tags: python, search, nlp, fuzzy-search

The phrases can be of at max length 4 words and the sentences can be of length at max 40 words.
Let's say the phrases are:

- three-course meal
- came with us
- in the end
- we ate much

and the sentences are :

1. We had a three-course meal.
2. Brad came to dinner with us.
3. In the end, we all felt like we ate too much.

Then,

- sentence 1 should match with `three-course meal`
- sentence 2 should match with `came with us`
- sentence 3 should match with `in the end` and `we ate much`

Earlier questions like - [Find occurrences of huge list of phrases in text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49173770/find-occurrences-of-huge-list-of-phrases-in-text) do not tackle fuzzy search which is needed in my case.

Comment: Why do you want to conduct a fuzzy search? All of your examples contain exactly the words of your phrases (no synonyms, no spelling issues). You can simply check if the sentence contains each word of a phrase and continue if this is the case.